# Nesting Block doesn't respect page.twig when Production

Tags: timber

Problem: In production enviroment Page.twig doesn't render as it should. Base.twig renders instead.
In development enviroment all work correctly. Both sites are totally equal (clone). The only difference is that production works on Apache, and development uses Nginx.

- Theme developed with Timber Starter Theme.
- WordPress 5.5.1
- PHP 7.2
- Timber 1.18.0

Page.twig

```
{% extends "base.twig" %}

{% block center_section %}
    <section id="content" role="main" class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 p-0 mb-4">
                {% block content %}
                    <h1 class="h2 font-libre m-0">{{post.title}}</h1>
                    <div class="content-wrapper">
                        <article class="post-type-{{post.post_type}} card content-wrapper border-0 no-border-radius p-3" id="post-{{post.ID}}">
                            <section class="article-content">
                                <div class="article-body">
                                    {{post.content}}
                                </div>
                            </section>
                        </article>
                    </div><!-- /content-wrapper -->
                {% endblock %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
{% endblock %}
```

Page.php

```
$context = Timber::context();
$timber_post     = new Timber\Post();
$context['post'] = $timber_post;
Timber::render( array( 'page-' . $timber_post->post_name . '.twig', 'page.twig' ), $context );
```

Comment: Fixed. It was some weired caching problem. I used this: reinstalled WP, installed twentytwenty theme, renamed my timber theme and enabled it. Worked. I just don't know why it was?

Comment: I was wrong. For some reason i copied extra instance of page.twig to the root of the theme! Haha.. Going to sleep now...